Visual Studio 2022 Synopys CodeSight BlackDuck extension Installed foler
I am interested in finding out how many developers in our org are leveraging the CodeSight-BlackDuck Synopsys detect visual studio 2022 plugin in their development work.
May I know to which folder the Synopsys Detect Visual studio IDE Plugin is installed.
